# Linux C using a serial device not working but commands in terminal work?

Tags: c, linux, embedded, embedded-linux

There is a problem with my C code:

I am trying to connect to a serial device, write a hex number to it and receive a hex response. I tried with all kinds of C code for writing data and reading, but I have NO RESPONSE at all. The device can be opened without error, but I cannot write and read.

However, if I run commands on a terminal, I can read from the device and save it into a file. Can anyone help with it? Also, I do notice I have to echo twice to read a response. The commands I use:

```
 stty -F /dev/ttymxc3 -echo -onlcr 9600
 cat /dev/ttymxc3 >rear.bin&
 echo -ne '\xfa\x03\xaa' > /dev/ttymxc3
 echo -ne '\xfa\x03\xaa' > /dev/ttymxc3
```

The test code I am using

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <time.h>

#define BAUDRATE B9600
#define DEVICE "/dev/ttymxc3"
#define HEX_DATA_LEN 3
#define HEX_DATA_SEND "\xfa\x03\xaa"
#define READ_INTERVAL_SEC 5
#define READ_COUNT 20

int main()
{
    int fd;
    struct termios oldtio, newtio;
    unsigned char buf[256];

    printf("Opening device %s\n", DEVICE);
    fd = open(DEVICE, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror(DEVICE);
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Setting terminal attributes...\n");
    tcgetattr(fd, &oldtio);
    bzero(&newtio, sizeof(newtio));
    newtio.c_cflag = BAUDRATE | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;
    newtio.c_iflag = IGNPAR;
    newtio.c_oflag = 0;
    newtio.c_lflag = 0;
    newtio.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    newtio.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);
    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &newtio);

    printf("Sending hex data...\n");
    write(fd, HEX_DATA_SEND, HEX_DATA_LEN);

    sleep(1);
    printf("Reading response...\n");
    int n = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
    if (n > 0) {
        printf("Received response: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            printf("0x%02x ", buf[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("Reading from device every %d seconds for %d times...\n", READ_INTERVAL_SEC, READ_COUNT);
    for (int i = 0; i < READ_COUNT; i++) {
        sleep(READ_INTERVAL_SEC);
        n = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
        if (n > 0) {
            printf("Received data: ");
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                printf("0x%02x ", buf[j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    printf("Closing device...\n");
    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &oldtio);
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"I tried with all kinds of the C++ code"_ - but what you've shown is C code, so I removed the C++ tag.

Comment: You may need to call `cfsetispeed()`and `cfsetospeed()`to set the baud rate. This is what I have in some working code I use (that I did not write).

Comment: You check whether the `open()` call succeeded — that's a good start.  You don't check whether other system calls succeed; you should!  At the command line, you use `-onlcr`; it is not clear that your C code handles that the same.  On the face of it, you should have something like `newtio.c_oflag &= ~ONLCR;` to clear the `-onlcr` flag and retain the other flags.  Only experimentation will tell you whether that's sufficient.  You may need to look at the method you're using to set `c_cflag` and `c_iflag` too.

Comment: You could consider running `system("stty -a -F " DEVICE);` after you've set the attributes, and also `stty -a -F /dev/ttymxc3` in your shell commands after you've set the terminal attributes and compare the outputs.  If there's a difference, you should consider it carefully and work out whether the difference causes the trouble.

Comment: Zeroing out the termios structure is bad coding! See [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Setting-Modes.html) Your program only checks for positive return codes, and neglects to report errors. Your shell commands uses whatever mode is last set, whereas the program tries to use noncanonical (aka raw) mode.

Comment: "*I do notice I have to echo twice to read a response.*" -- Then whatever is on the other end of your serial link is not a reliable responder. Since your program only sends the "command" one time, expecting a response may be unreasonable (aside from all the other issues that the code may have). IOW your title is not an accurate description of the situation; your program is not a replication of the shell commands.